# Selenium. Не получается поймать 500е ошибки

Tags: java, selenium, httpurlconnection

Код, который должен ловить статус загрузки страницы

```
public static int getResponseCode(String urlString) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
    huc.connect();
    return huc.getResponseCode();}

private static int statusCode;
```

Цикл, в котором я проверяю статус по страницам

```
for(int i = 0; i < url.length; i++)
        {try {driver.get(url[i]);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        statusCode = getResponseCode(url[i]);
        if(statusCode >= 300){System.out.println("HTTP code "+statusCode+" on "+url[i]);}
        else {System.out.println("Code is "+statusCode);}}
        catch (Exception e){System.out.println("Exception. Probably 50X");}}
```

Я использую `catch (Exception e)` потому что не могу поймать 500е статусы загрузки, может я делаю что-то не так?

Answer (score 1):

[Вроде](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.de/2012/07/webdriver-y-u-no-have-http-status-codes.html) как они отказались от такой феньки.

Но статус все еще можно прочесть отправив свой реквест к серверу по урлу с помощью HtmlUnit:

```
try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
    WebClientOptions options = webClient.getOptions();
    options.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    WebResponse webResponse = webClient.getPage("https://url.com").getWebResponse();
    int code = webResponse.getStatusCode();
} catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: в своем тесте я прохожу по внутренним страницам после того, как залогинился, эта команда для этого требует дополнительных параметров авторизации?

Comment: Да, вам тогда придется сначало запостить логин реквест, что бы сессию для ХЮ клиента создать, а потом можно сразу пробивать что там за статускод. Если авторизация через куки, то может быть можно как то куком поделится...

Comment: Что то мне эта команда огромную кучу мусора в лог выбрасывает. Я не вполне понимаю даже что за инфу она выбрасывает (в частности кусок кода страницы)

Comment: @DmitryFeniks Это просто эррор стрим, код подправил.

Comment: как можно передать параметры авторизации перед проверкой статуса загрузки?

Comment: Там же просто какая то форма отсылается на сервер с 2-3 параметрами, что типа http://url.com/login?user=bla&pass=blabla&rem=false - можно посмотреть в хроме на вкладке нетворкс, когда обычным путем, через браузер залогинитесь